# Return success when handling error in a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, promise

I have a promise that handles a HTTP request performed over a Web API:

```
promise = promise.then(r => { 
    // ...
  }, error => {
    if (error.status == 404) {
      // Here I can fix an error and continue properly
    } else {
      // Here the error should be propagated further in the promise
    }
}

// later in the code:
promise.catch(r => { /* More error handling */ } );
```

Later in the code this promise is chained to more error checks.

In case of a 404 error, I can actually "fix" a problem, and I don't want the other handler to trigger. I'd rather want to make the promise a success in this case. How can I do that?

---

A bit more code to explain my case more deeply:

```
refresh() {
  this.refreshAsync().catch(r => {
     // Show error to the user.
     notifications.showError("Unexpected error happened");
  });
}

async refreshAsync() {
  // Here goes a lot of vue-resource calls to gather the necessary data for a view. They are chained with `await`. Only one of them:
  await this.$http.get(url).then(r => {
    this.data = r.data;
  }, error => {
    // 404 is actually a legit response for API to return, so the user notification above should not be shown
    if (error.status == 404) {
      // handle successfully
    } else {
      // propagate an error, so the handler above could show a warning to the user.
    }

  });

}
```

Comment: How is your `promise` declared ? You'll have to detect the 404 error and call `reject()`.

Comment: can you show us how do you intend to handle the success case?

Comment: @Zenoo This is a promise returned by `vue-resource`. I'm not in control of declaration

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay please see the update

Comment: Have you tried using [interceptor](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return a reject/resolve

```
if(error.status == 404)
    return Promise.resolve('OK')
else
    return Promise.reject('fail')
```

I made an example showing how this work,
just for this case:

```
httpRequest = function () {
  return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
    let status = (Math.round(Math.random()) === 1) ? 200 : 404;
    console.log(status)
    if (status === 200)
        return res({ status })
    else
        return rej({ status })
  })
}

let promise =
httpRequest()
    .then(res => Promise.resolve('success'))
    .catch(e => {
        if (e.status === 404)
            return Promise.resolve('success')
        else
            return Promise.reject('failed')
    })

promise
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log('this should not happen')
})
```

Comment: Doesn't really work (or I didn't understood your idea): https://jsfiddle.net/m0g23kzj/

Comment: I think you're not using promise formally, it's not like stream or observable, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0g23kzj/1/)

Comment: You are totally right, I've made a mistake in the code. Jsfiddle now works correctly.  I will test it with my code a bit later and accept the answer if it works

Comment: I made a edition, to show how it works in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to propagate your success flow when you "fix" it, I can think of two approaches here,

1. You can wrap your further propagation logic in a function and then call it in the error scenario.
2. Wrap your `promise` in another promise and call `resolve(yourValue)` on error 404. But then this will mean you'll have to change your further chained logics on the `promise` object, but on the contrary this will give you more flexibility.

Hope it helps ;)

**EDIT**

After seeing your code, I still feel it is achievable by what I have mentioned before. You can do something on the lines of -

```
refreshAsync = async () => {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       await this.$http.get(url).then(r => {
           this.data = r.data;
        }, error => {
            if (error.status == 404) {
                 resolve(); //populate this with your desired value
           } else {
                 reject();
           }
   })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both options seem like a move to the code that is harder to read or support. I really didn't expect such a simple case not being possible to do in a simple way with `Promise`. BTW, please see my update to the question - maybe it will give you more insight

Comment: although, i think you have marked the answer, does this help? @Archeg

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is very helpful. I think I had a wrong understanding of how `Promise` work, so I need to work on that more. Your approach should be helpful if you work with custom `Promise` implementation, that is nonstandard (which is often the case for many libraries). In my case I found out that I use a standard implementation (I thought that I'm not, but I confused myself). Anyway thank you for the response. The whole question with all the answers is gold for me, I've got much useful information here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [standard `Promise` implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can simply just throw an error and then it will be returned as a failed promise result to the next `catch` method:

```js
// let's assume we have the following async operation
const somePromiseCall = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000))

somePromiseCall()
  .then(() => {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      throw 'this is the error message'
    }

    return 'this is the result'
  })
  .then(result => console.log('success', result))
  .catch(err => console.error('fail', err))
```

Another way to do this is just by returning another promise that you can immediately reject (either by returning `new Promise((resolve, reject)=>reject('error message'))` or by returning the shorthand method `Promise.reject('error message')`:

```js
// let's assume we have the following async operation
const somePromiseCall = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000))

somePromiseCall()
  .then(() => {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      return Promise.reject('error message')
    }

    return 'this is the result'
  })
  .then(result => console.log('success', result))
  .catch(err => console.error('fail', err))
```

The reason why the second version works is because any return value from a `then` or `catch` method is wrapped in a promise and passed on so you can chain `then` calls.
Knowing this, if you return a value, the `then` method, behind the scenes, actually returns something like `Promise.resolve(returnValue)`, so that you can do chaining:

```
somePromiseCall()
  .then(result => result + 1)
  .then(newResult => /* newResult === result + 1 */)
```

That's why the above snippet is similar to this one:

```
somePromiseCall()
  .then(result => Promise.resolve(result + 1))
  .then(newResult => /* newResult === result + 1 */)
```

Having this in mind, you can also return a rejected promise that actually can be caught with the `catch` method:

```
somePromiseCall()
  .then(result => Promise.reject('reason'))
  .catch(err => console.log('error', err))
```